# Can'f find ".htaccess" file on File Manager

Tags: html

so when I connect to the File Manager I see those folders:

- .pki
- domains
- imap
- maildir
- public_html

However, when I go to public.html it directs me to the folder that is located domains/mydomain.com/public-html where I only see the files that I've uploaded by myself.So I can't find .htaccess file, I hope somebody can help me.

If there is no way to find it, I could create it.. but where should I upload it ?
Also I marked on FileZilla to show hidden files, but nothing hasn't changed.

Comment: If there is no `.htaccess` file, then you create one by yourself. Put this file in the `public_html` folder. It's also possible that these files are hidden, depends on the FTP client you are using.

Answer (score 0):

dot files may be hidden in your file manager. So go to your settings and tick display hidden or dot files. or a dialogue box will appear when you click on file manager icon in cpanel there also you can find the option to display hidden files

Answer (score 0):

go to file manger  then press settings and tick display hidden or dot files

More details

How to Show Hidden Files cpanel File Manager

Delete Files in hidden subdirectories  Cpanel

https://youtu.be/GrBzqrE11M8